# Type Graphql custom Resolver

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

Iam have a User ObjectType and want in my LoginResolver, to return the user and a generated token for that user as an Object like so:

`{user:User, token:string}`
Currently I can return either the User OR a string, depending on the Type i give in the @Mutation() decorator

```
@Mutation((returns) => User)
  async login(
    @Arg("email") email: string,
    @Arg("password") password: string,
    @Ctx("ctx") ctx: IContext
  ) {
    const user = await this.userRepo.findOneUser({ where: { email } });
    const success = await compare(password, user.password);
    if (!success) ctx.throw(401);
    const token = await this.tokenRepo.createToken(user);

    return user;
  }
```

when i try creating an UserWIthToken Objecttype I get the following Error for every field on the user entity:

````
app_1       |   error: [ValidationError: Cannot query field "id" on type "UserWithToken".] {
app_1       |     locations: [ [Object] ],
app_1       |     path: undefined,
app_1       |     extensions: { code: 'GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED', exception: [Object] }
app_1       |   }
app_1       | }```
dont mind the app_1 here, Iam using docker
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom ObjectType for this case

```
@ObjectType()
class UserWithToken {
    @Field(() => User)
    user: User
      
    @Field()
    token: string
}
```

Then use that object in your query instead of user

```
@Query((returns) => UserWithToken)
async login(
    @Arg("email") email: string,
    @Arg("password") password: string,
    @Ctx("ctx") ctx: IContext
) : Promise<UserWithToken> {
    const user = await this.userRepo.findOneUser({ where: { email } });
    const success = await compare(password, user.password);
    if (!success) ctx.throw(401);
    const token = await this.tokenRepo.createToken(user);

    return {
        user,
        token
    };
}
```

Please note I used `@Query` here instead of `@Mutation` as it fit this case better, as a rule of thumb if you want to read data without modifying it, use Query, other wise for deleting/adding/editing data use Mutation.

Then you can run the login query like this

```
query {
  login(email: "xx@xx.com", password: "xxxxx") {
    token
    user {
      id
      name
      email
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, I updated the question, I still get some errors

Comment: it seems you're trying to query user's fields directly from `UserWithToken` object, I updated the answer on how to query user's data correctly.

Comment: ah right, i didnt update the query accordinly thank you :)

Comment: It's possible that e.g. `tokenRepo.createToken` can write the timestamp in the column of db to log the last issue date, so in that case it's better to use mutation. Also from the client perspective, when we issue the token by a query it means that apollo can use cached value while for mutation it will always be executed.

Comment: Thanks @MichałLytek I've never thought of that case!